# Editing all occurrences of a string within a lists-within-list object

Tags: r

Example data:

```
ds <- data.frame(q1 = c(1:3), q1b = c(1:3), q1c = c(1:3), q2 = c(1:3), q2b = c(1:3), q2c = c(1:3))

filterList <- list()
filterList[[1]] <- list(var= "q1", filterFor= c("q1b", "q1c"))
filterList[[2]] <- list(var= "q2", filterFor= c("q2b", "q2c"))
```

I have a data frame containing survey data, and a lists-within-list setup to keep track of filters. Eg. "only ask q1b if a certain answer was given in q1". The actual filter conditions are stored elsewhere, the lists-within-list setup is just there to help me keep track of dependencies.

I'm working on a function that will allow me to rename a variable (eg. q1) in both the data frame, and the list at the same time. In other words, I need a function that can rename every occurrence of the string "q1" to "Question 1", within both objects defined in the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function changes values of global variables, bouth to data.frame and list

```
renameF <- function(xold, xnew){
  colnames(ds) <<- gsub(xold, xnew, colnames(ds))
  filterList <<- lapply(filterList, function(x)
    lapply(x, function(y) gsub(xold, xnew, y)))
  return(NULL)
}


renameF("q1", "Question1")
ds
  Question1 Question1b Question1c Question2 Question2b Question2c
1         1          1          1         1          1          1
2         2          2          2         2          2          2
3         3          3          3         3          3          3



filterList
[[1]]
[[1]]$var
[1] "Question1"

[[1]]$filterFor
[1] "Question1b" "Question1c"


[[2]]
[[2]]$var
[1] "Question2"

[[2]]$filterFor
[1] "Question2b" "Question2c"
```